# ViewResult or ActionResult | does it makes sense to use ViewResult if ActionResult is good for everything anyways?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In asp.net mvc there is ViewResult for returning a View and ActionResult for returning whatever you want, so is there some good reason why should I use ViewResult instead of ActionResult when I'm sure that I will return a View ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ActionResult` is the general base class that all the other results are derived from like `ViewResult`,`JsonResult` and so on.

This way you can return multiple types of results like JSON and XML from the same method.

Comment: does it makes any difference, like for example the page is going be rendered faster, or there is going to be less memory used with ViewResult instead of ActionResult or something like that ?

Comment: No it doesn't really matter at all. The ASP.NET MVC convention is having the return type be `ActionResult` and you return a derived type.

Answer (score 6):

It's for the same reason you don't write every method of every class to return "object". You should be as specific as you can. This is especially valuable if you're planning to write unit tests. No more testing return types and/or casting the result.

Comment: If you are too specific, you will couple your methods with their implementation. For example, return `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `T[]` allows the return of arrays, collections, lists etc.. Provide enough context to get the developer moving, whilst still allowing you to change the design underneath. But is there any reason why you would write a test to check that the return type is `ViewResult`, when the method is declared as returning `ViewResult`? If it was `ActionResult`, then it would have value.

Answer (score 4):

You should use ViewResult to make code more readable and find bugs easier, but there can be other benefits too.

Since I use POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern, I wrote some tests to check if every [HttpPost] method returns RedirectToRouteResult. If I define other type of result in [HttpPost] method, it automatically doesn't pass test. This prevents me from returning View(model) in post method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do unit testing then change it in the controller from ActionResult to ViewResult.  Then you will have the intellisense in your Test Controller and life is good.

Answer (score 0):

I just accidentally got same question some days ago and google came to help quickly. Basically there is no performance issue here, it's coding issue if any.

This is a short but useful blog post: http://www.techiesblog.com/post/2862100163/viewresult-vs-actionresult-asp-net-mvc

Comment: That link is not very helpful, as it requires you to supply a password before you can see the page, but offers no way to register for the site.

Comment: It was not at the time I replied here. It seems that not a login form as usual, the author likely made his blog private.